# Best C# library for charts

Tags: library, c#, charts, raspberry-pi

I was looking for UWP chart C# library but I could not find that one that could help to solve my problem. So far I have used library from Syncfusion and LiveCharts but they have some problems so I wanted to ask If someone could help.

I am looking for C# library for UWP where I can make line X Y dependent chart (X axis for DateTime and Y axis for some value). And I need to display approx. every second a new point and I need to store that point on chart for 24 hours. And it should be free for use in noncommercial application because my app is opensource.The app will be running on Raspberry Pi 3.

Thanks for any help <3

Comment: I am from Syncfusion and can help if you specify what problem you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

[Syncfusion Essential Chart for UWP](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/uwp/sfchart) supports DateTime for X axis and Y values to create a chart as per your requirements . Please try this [sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/174921/ze/RealTimeChart955737923) code.

[image: Syncfusion UWP Chart]

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense?refer=srecs39882) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use XAML to add charts to your user interface either through the UI designer or through XAML code, then use the out-of-the-box APIs in C#. This can be as easy as:

```
Chart1.Series.Add("SeriesA");
```

Otherwise, you can use System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.